# jQuery get DOM node?

Tags: jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

I can select a node using jQuery with something like `$('#element_id')` but how would I get the DOM element for use with non-jQuery functions that expect something like would be returned by `document.getElementById()`?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can retrieve DOM elements using array notation:

```
$("#element_id")[0]
```

or with `get()`:

```
$("#element_id").get(0)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you :) I was looking through the jQuery API but I wasn't quite sure what to look for. All I found was `.context`.

Comment: **Not working** with DOM's attribute nodeValue. Ex. `$("#element_id").[0].nodeValue`... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18418270/287948 and http://jsfiddle.net/b80nskbw/

Comment: @PeterKrauss `[0]` is not a method call -- remove the dot. `$("#element_id")[0].nodeValue` works.