# How to make $('#some-id') return the same object as getElementById('some-id')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

I have a JavaScript library that takes one of parameters as

```
element: document.getElementById('file-uploader')
```

And it works well, though I try to use jQuery instead and error happens then.

```
element: $('#file-uploader')
```

I suppose these return different objects so how can I make it with jQuery but return an object of the same kind as if it were returned by `getElementById` method?

Comment: There are at least 2 same questions answered already: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316199/jquery-get-dom-node 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector

Answer (score 5):

Try -

```
$('#file-uploader')[0] //or $('#file-uploader').get(0)
```

This will return the 'naked' JavaScript DOM object, the same as

```
document.getElementById('file-uploader')
```

would return. The example above will only return the first element of the matched set, but in a situation where you're searching by id that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#file-uploader')[0]
```

It should be equiv to:

```
document.getElementById('file-uploader')
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use either [0] or .get(0) to return the dom object instead of the jquery:

```
$('#file-uploader')[0];
```

or

```
$('#file-uploader').get(0);
```