# jQuery Javascript pass parent object as this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, closures

I want to pass the currently called object with it's currently set parameters on to a closure function.  I'm not sure how to do this in general, but then I think jQuery adds another layer of confusion because this refers to an element.

Example:

## jQuery Plugin

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.addContentType = function(obj) {
    var name = "this is just an example";
    obj.func.call(this); //<--I want to pass this object, not the jQuery selector   
  };
})( jQuery );
```

## Call to Plugin

```
jQuery("#someelement").addContentType({
  func:function(){
    console.log(this.name); //<--Expect "this is just an example"
  }
});
```

Any ideas how to do this?

This is just an example and doesn't do anything, I'm just trying to show what I'm after.  If I am missing details, let me know.

Comment: You can't get local variables.

Comment: `name` is just a local variable inside `addContentType`. `this` on the other hand refers to all elements selected by `jQuery("#someelement")`. Hence, `this.name` is the same as `jQuery("#someelement").name`.

Comment: @Felix: Correct.  I mentioned that in the beginning.  I was asking if there was a way to pass a "this" that would refer to the object itself

Comment: Which object to you mean? The selected element? Or the jQuery object? What if multiple elements are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `name` as a property of the jQuery object, you'd need to add it instead of using a variable.

```
this.name = "this is just an example";
obj.func.call(this);
```

---

Or use the variable to pass the value to the function:

```
var name = "this is just an example";
obj.func.call(this, name);
```

and receive it on the other end:

```
func:function( name ){
   console.log( name ); //<--Expect "this is just an example"
}
```

---

Or to make your `obj` the `this` value, do this:

```
obj.func.call(obj, name);
```

...but you still need to pass the argument unless you assign the value as a property to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply()` to pass both context and arguments from the original function call:

```
obj.func.apply(this, arguments);
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for `.apply()` and [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

You get DOM element from jQuery selector like this:

```
$("#elem").get(0);
```

or

```
$("#elem")[0];
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector) for detailed info (if you need it)