# Jquery Element Usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

I know using normal javascript i can do

```
formitem.validity.valid
```

or

```
formitem.checkValidity();
```

How do i use Jquery to call these functions?
Below im using a custom attribute selector to get my element but cant seem to use it like below...

```
$('[data-dependID=pobText]').validity.valid
```

or

```
$('[data-dependID=pobText]').formitem.checkValidity();
```

Simple but how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get DOM Node for that:

```
$('[data-dependID=pobText]').get(0).validity.valid;
$('[data-dependID=pobText]').get(0).formitem.checkValidity();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Get,

i.e.

```
$('[data-dependID=pobText]').get(0).formitem.checkValidity();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.get(n)` to get the nth element as a DOM object, or just `[n]`

```
$('selector').get(n).foo
```

or

```
$('selector')[n].foo
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery calls to the DOM return an array-like object and so you can access the DOM elements in the "array" by an index. The `get()` method does the same thing, only that it encapsulates this in a function call (which is an overhead).

Better use the index instead:

```
$('[data-dependID=pobText]')[n].validity.valid;
$('[data-dependID=pobText]')[n].checkValidity();
```