# JQuery selector not grabbing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying a relatively simple jQuery selector, similar to those I've done hundreds of times before, something like :

```
$('.fail_vid')
```

However, instead of returning the the element like I expect, i.e.

```
<div class="fail_vid"></div>
```

it spits out something like

```
<div>, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: #document, selector: ".fail_vid"
```

What's going on? I've never seen anything like this, and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, can you provide an example?

Comment: what are you doing? If logging to console, this is expected behavior.

Comment: What are you doing with the selector to cause it to "spit something out"?  I suspect the problem lies there.

Comment: I noticed that after updating chrome

Comment: That is how the new "Chrome web inspector" outputs a jQuery object, and it's totally normal, even if it's completely unreadable.

Comment: Alright. I have a RoR partial in which I'm calling some JavaScript. I suspect the jQuery selector is firing before the partial itself is loaded, which is why it's not finding anything.
How can I get my JS to fire AFTER the partial's been completely loaded?

Comment: I think it **did** find something. The first item in the array `<div>` is the element found!

Comment: There seems to be one element found, noted by the `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]` containing one indexed property.

Answer (score 2):

The output you're getting is a jQuery object as output by Chrome (23 I think). Elements associated are stored as array indexes. So anything without a key is an element.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense. I'm actually trying to grab something inside of a RoR partial.
Based on your comment and the thread above, I suspect the selector is being called before the partial has properly rendered.
What's the best way to prevent this?

Comment: @AdamTempleton The `<div>` in your output is a DOMElement (notice how it doesn't have a key, it's an array index as in my answer). So your selector is probably working. You can use `console.log($('.fail_vid').length);` to see if you are selecting anything.

Comment: @Jasper Wouldn't `.eq(0)` just give you another jQuery object?

Answer (score 2):

The output you're seeing is simply a representation of the jQuery object returned by the `$('.fail_vid')` statement.

If you want the actual DOM element, use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to retrieve it:

```
$('.fail_vid').get(0)
```

You can also access the array of elements directly, like so:

```
$('.fail_vid')[0]
```

This only retrieves the *first* DOM element selected by your selector. If your selector selects *more than one* DOM element, subsequent elements can be retrieved at higher indices. You can also retrieve *all* elements at once, as an array, by calling `.get()` without any arguments.

*Related question: [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)*

---

To make sure the script is executed only after all DOM elements are loaded, you can either include the script at the end of your document, or use [**$(document).ready()**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29).