# HTML Line Controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, controls, purify

I have a manipulated HTML text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="#">dolor</a> sit amet
<div>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do </div> eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I need to convert these lines into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#">dolor</a> sit amet</p>
<div>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do </div>
<p>eiusmod tempor</p>
<p>incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
```

How to convert? Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little lengthy, so please read carefully. I have annotated the important parts to give a general idea as to the flow of the function.

```
function paragraphify(parent) {
    var i, str, p, workspace = document.createElement('div'), nodes = parent.childNodes;

    p = document.createElement('p');
    workspace.appendChild(p);

    // Filter nodes out of parent and into the workspace.
    while(nodes.length > 0) {
        // Get the first child node of the parent element.
        node = nodes[0];

        // Divs and paragraphs need not be processed; skip them.
        if(node.nodeName === 'P' || node.nodeName === 'DIV') {
            workspace.insertBefore(node, p);
            continue;
        }

        // Drop the node into the paragraph.
        p.appendChild(node);

        // Skip non-text nodes.
        if(node.nodeName !== '#text') { continue; }

        // We need to parse the text of the node for newlines.
        str = node.nodeValue;
        for(i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
            if(str[i] === '\n') {
                // If text contains a newline ...

                if(i < (str.length - 1)) {
                    // ... and there's enough space to split it, then split it.
                    parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(str.substr(i+1)), nodes[0]);
                    node.nodeValue = str.substr(0, i+1);
                }

                // Create a new paragraph for holding elements, and add it to the workspace.
                p = document.createElement('p');
                workspace.appendChild(p);

                // Break here to return to the node-processing loop.
                // If the text was split on a newline, then that will be the next node to be processed.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Pull the nodes back out of the workspace and into the parent element.
    nodes = workspace.children;
    while(nodes.length > 0) {
        node = nodes[0];

        // Skip empty paragraphs.
        if(node.nodeName === 'P' && node.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').length === 0) {
            workspace.removeChild(node);
        }
        else {
            parent.appendChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This function will do as you have specified in your example. **`Paragraphify`** iterates through the children nodes of the `parent` argument, skipping `<div>` and `<p>` elements, as those need not be formatted. It creates a paragraph node and moves the parent's nodes in, one at a time, until it encounters a newline character within a text node, at which time it splits the text node appropriately.

This is processed until the parent element is empty. The workspace elements are then transferred back into parent. This was done to make processing much simpler, as manipulating a collection that you are actively iterating can be messy.

---

I should warn that this does not descend further than the parent's immediate children, but if you have this need, please let me know. To put that basically, this function would not perform this translation:

```
<span>Hello
world</span>
```

... into ...

```
<p><span>Hello</span></p>
<p><span>world</span></p>
```

Even then, this should be a good example of the base functionality required for line processing in HTML with basic Javascript.

[**jsFiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/bX4LV/)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! This is really a hardwork! I think this will solve my problem. It seems, "Parent" has to be a DOM element? and how about jQuery?

Comment: That is correct, as shown in the jsFiddle demonstration. I used a `div` with the ID attribute of `container`.

Comment: As for jQuery, if you mean using this function with it, all you should need to do is [retrieve the DOM node from the jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector). If this answer has fully satisfied your needs, please tick the green checkmark to let everyone know that this is the chosen one. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: That looks like it would accomplish your task at a very basic level, but always keep in mind that [parsing HTML with regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) is not infallible. If you wanted to get the textual result of using `paragraphify`, you could make use of the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) property.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best effort: [demo here](http://ideone.com/Ixqy5g). Obviously you need a more sophisticated solution. You might want to look at the wordpress formatting API and the [wpautop](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php) function.

You will need to do some *major edits* on the regular expression (`"/^<\\/?div|^<\\/?ul|^<\\/?li|<\\/?p/"`) and function, but at least this will get you started!

Comment: Oh crap, how silly! Sorry about that, I thought you needed PHP!

Comment: It happens :) Thank you anyway!