# Access angular template element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering what the correct angular way to access the main html template element. I can use getelementbyid and also can access it using attr.$$element[0] but wondering if there is a cleaner way. In the example below I would like the equivalent of the getElementById line.

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      // what is angular way of doing this?
      var canvas = initCanvas(document.getElementById("test-canvas")),
      // this works - is this recommended method?
      var canvas = attr.$$element[0];

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: If you want to access the 'main html template element' just use the `elem` param. It's already a reference to the template root element.

Comment: In the link function, `elem` is a jQuery (or jQuery lite) wrapped DOM element corresponding to the element the directive is operating on. However, it's possible in some cases that this is a _copy_ of the original element, which may or may not be important for your needs. You can get the _actual_ original element in these rare cases via the `compile` function of the directive.

Comment: First thing I tried but it doesn't work. It is the element but not in the same format as that returned by the other options and it's not useable for me - in my case I want to do some canvas work and need to call canvas.getContext('2d') - and getContext is not a function of elem.

Comment: Actually elem[0] works - why the array call though?

Comment: Because `elem` is a jQuery wrapped element. `elem[0]` returns the raw element that has been wrapped. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1677910/62082

Comment: Ahhh!! I got it - it doesnt look like Angular has the .get() function so I guess elem[0] would be the way to go for my needs.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `elem` param like so:

```
var canvas = elem;
```

it's a `jqLite (jQuery)` wrapped element as was mention in the comments.

or

```
var canvas = elem[0];
```

to get a raw element.

If you want to get access to children elements and do something with them, you should use `angular.element`. Angular uses `jqLite`, it provides limited `jQuery` methods. You can read further here: [Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). For instance, in `jqLite` you can use `find()` only with the tag name selector, so if you want to select the child by id you should use something like that:

```
angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('#your_child')).bind('click', () => {
  elem.toggleClass('some_class');
}
```

If you are using jQuery, you are able to use `find()`, then the code will look like that:

```
elem.find('#your_child').click(() => {
    elem.toggleClass('some_class');
});
```

Try out `console.log(elem)` you will see what it is. Hope this helps!

P.S.: Let's say you want to select child elements from the `ng-repeat` directive. The previous solutions won't work because these elements don't exist yet. All you need to do is to add `$timeout` like so:

```
function yourDirective($timeout) {
  return {
    ...
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      $timeout(() => {
        angular.element(elem[0].querySelectorAll('.your_child')).bind('click', () => {
          // Do something
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

angular
  .module('yourApp')
  .directive('yourDirective', yourDirective);
```