# Color Thief won’t work …

Tags: javascript

I’d like to use [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief), a script which allows you to extract the dominant color of an image.

Unfortunately I’m not able to get the code to work. I’d like the dominant color to be the background color of a div called `mydiv`.

Here’s what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/srd5y/4/

**Updated code / transfered to my own server due to cross-linking issues: http://moargh.de/daten/color-thief-master/test.html**

JS

```
var sourceImage = 'https://www.google.de/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif';
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in the jsfiddle, color-thief.js contains HTML markup instead of javascript. Check the error console.

Comment: sorry for that—it’s fixed.

Comment: For your fiddle example I don't think Color Thief can cross-domain

Comment: @Murtnowski: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Updated Code-> Are you allowing time for the image to load before using Color Thief?  Try `$(window).ready(handlerFunction)`.  The color for the updated code image should be [125, 190, 193]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this based on your code and a mix of everyone's answers.  You need to wait for the image to load before using Color Theif.  The color for photo1.jpg should be [125, 190, 193]

Thanks @Shadow Wizard and @ejegg

See [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin)

**EDIT**: Ok use this fiddle which works http://jsfiddle.net/bgYkT/

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/color-thief.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        #mydiv {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <img src="img/photo1.jpg" id="myimg" />

    <div id="mydiv"></div>


    <script>
      $(window).ready(function(){
        var sourceImage = document.getElementById("myimg");
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();
        var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
        document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")";
       });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I added the handler but it still does not work. http://moargh.de/daten/color-thief-master/test.html

Comment: @user1706680 Missing end ) on line 42

Answer (score 8):

Murtnowski is correct in saying that the operation will fail if you run it against an image hosted on a different domain.  If you are running it on an image hosted on your own domain, you just need to call getColor with an img element rather than a URL:

HTML

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" id="myImg" />
```

JS

```
var sourceImage = document.getElementById("myImg");
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

Comment: Thanks, I build in your suggestions and uploaded it to my own server due to the cross-linking issue: http://moargh.de/daten/color-thief-master/test.html How do I get the value of the `colorThief` variable?

Comment: @user1706680 you need to manually set it e.g. `var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage); document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")";`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code but it still doesn’t work … I also added the event handler Murtnowski suggested.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled for a few hours to get `color-thief` to work.
In the end it was the tiny addition of `[0]` to point to the first array element:

```
<img id="theimage" src="images/p1-340-thumb.jpg" />

myImage = $('#theimage');
colorThief = new ColorThief();
color = colorThief.getColor(myImage[0]);
red = color[0];
green = color[1];
blue = color[2];
```

Comment: Good catch. jQuery wrapped sets are not their underlying DOM elements, and many libraries require you to pass a DOM element. This has bitten me several times. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem, and solved it this way :

```
// get my image url
var imageUrl = '//myimage.ulr.com';
// than create an image elm, the sizes are needed. 360x360 on this case
var image = new Image(360, 360);


image.onload = function(){
    // act only after image load
    console.log(image);

    // than colorThief and get the color value 
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();          
    var color = colorThief.getColor(image);
    console.log(color);
};
image.src = imageUrl;
```

Hope it helps anyone

Comment: I cannot get this to work... I'm ultimately trying to pull in the background image of an element, but even simplifying it down to your example, with the url explicitly defined... I still get nothing. Any ideas why? http://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/xEAAWE