# Color Thief Palette array not outputting correctly

Tags: jquery, color-picker

Wanted to play and have a reason to learn more jQuery so I decided to try my hand at [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) but I am having an issue outputting the array correctly.  Sadly, the documentation isn't the greatest for Color Thief but after some searching I did find a question in regards to [`getColor()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600644/color-thief-wont-work) but not getPalette().

From my understanding of Color Thief's blog was `createPalette()` is an array but when I try to display the contents it stays within on `<span>`:

### Code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="imgtest">
<img id="theimage" src="item.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function(){
          var sourceImage = document.getElementById("theimage");
          var colorThief = new ColorThief();
          var color = [colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage, 2)];
          var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
              return('<span>' + value + '</span>');
          });
          $("#results").html(newHTML.join(""));
       });
</script>
```

Output:

```
<span>205,144,9,245,228,217,172,196,11</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?  My end goal to is display each color in array called `color[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right in thinking you want each color within it's own span, you need to join the values within the mapping. Each value of `color` is an array containing the color's RGB values:

```
var color = colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage, 2);
var newHTML = $.map(color, function(value) {
    return('<span>' + value.join(', ') + '</span>');
});
$("#results").html(newHTML.join(''));
```

Comment: That should be `<span>119, 175, 169</span><span>214, 191, 131</span><span>53, 37, 28</span>` which is all on one line. If you need them on different lines, change your markup.

Comment: ah you're right I see what that was.  Thanks and plus one for the help.  If you dont mind can you explain what the `(', ')` is doing?

Comment: Yes, `join()` will concatenate the array values (`[r,g,b]`) with the string that you pass to it (a comma and a space). See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)