# javascript color thief in jquery nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have some dynamically generated content on which I need to use color thief to find the dominant colour. Here's the final dynamic output:

```
<div class="image_product">
    <img style="display:none;" src="image1.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="image2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image_product">
    <img style="display:none;" src="image3.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="image4.jpg">
</div>
```

And here's the script I'm trying:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
$('div.image_product').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        var color = colorThief.getColor(this[0]);
        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

I've managed to get it working in other areas where I know there is only one image, with the following code:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
$('div.basket_item_image').each(function() {
    if($(this).children("img").length > 0)
    {
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        var color = colorThief.getColor(img[0]);
        console.log(color);
    }
});
```

And I know you have to add the `[0]` when using it with JQuery to make it access the DOM correctly, but I can't see how my middle code isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid you do, hence I've used it on the last working example. I couldn't get it to work for ages until I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235248/1170039) and now it works.

Comment: Why are you using 'div.image_product' in one, and 'div.basket_item_image' in the other?

Comment: @judgeja because in the working example this is the class name of the relevant divs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `this[0]`. Inside `each()`, `this` is *the current HTML element being iterated* and not a jQuery object, per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

Therefore, just use `this` to access the current element (the current `<img />`) whilst inside `each()`.

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
$('div.image_product').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        var color = colorThief.getColor(this);
        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns; I'm afraid you don't. When you call `each()` on a jQuery object, jQuery invokes the callback you pass for each element in the jQuery object. Inside that callback, `this` is the raw DOM element, not a jQuery object. If it *was* a jQuery object, you **would** have to use `this[0]`, but it's not, so you don't.

Comment: OK, but `this` on it's own doesn't work. I see why you shouldn't need `[0]`, but then why doesn't it work?! So confused!

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns: Can you come up with a jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem? I can't even get colorThief to work for me... the library throws an exception on line 131.

Comment: I'm afraid not... I can't get the cross domain images to work. I think it has to be local.