# Using Color Thief Library in React doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, color-thief

I am struggling to add Color Thief in a react app. I have followed the instruction on github but nothing changes.
I have applied the suggestions reporte [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600644/color-thief-won-t-work) and then inserted the scripts inside a setTimeout function, but I get always the same error:

[image: error]

Can you please help me to run this library (or similars if you have alternatives) in react?

Here is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
var ColorThief = require('color-thief');

function App() {
 setTimeout(function(){
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var img = 'img.jpg';
    var palette = colorThief.getPalette(img, 8);
    var dominant =  colorThief.getColor(img);
    console.log(palette);
    console.log(dominant);
    document.getElementById("app").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + dominant + ")";
 }, 3000);

return (
    <div id="app"></div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `getPalette`/`getColor` doesn't expect a string as parameter.

Comment: how can I pass the image, then?

Comment: For `getColor` there's a `getColorFromUrl`, but since you also need `getPalette`, I suggest having a look at the source code at https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/blob/fedd83af85f4844c4732d967057323caf0cd0f6e/src/color-thief.js#L141 Create an image element, and after it's loaded, pass it down to the functions you've already used.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that doesn't work neither. For the sake of detail I console.log the colorThief var and it turn out to be an empty object. That means that var ColorThief = require('color-thief'); doesn't return anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the solution? because i'm struggling with this

Comment: @Yorbjörn the solutions down below are quite good. Another one could be a rewriting of this lib into es6, unfortunatelly

Comment: Thanks for response, fortunately I found another package that does the trick for me.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rgbaster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the library with npm:

```
$ npm i --save colorthief
```

Import the library in your file as:

```
import ColorThief from "colorthief";
```

Create a **react reference** to your image like so:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Image element reference
    this.imgRef = React.createRef();
  }
```

The image component should look like this:

```
          <img
            crossOrigin={"anonymous"}
            ref={this.imgRef}
            src={
              "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516876437184-593fda40c7ce"
            }
            alt={"example"}
            className={"example__img"}
            onLoad={() => {
              const colorThief = new ColorThief();
              const img = this.imgRef.current;
              const result = colorThief.getColor(img, 25);
            }}
          />
```

( **Please note,** the image props should be in this exact order)

Comment: like a charm!!!

Comment: Attempting to install the `colorthief` package hangs during installation. when using `--verbose` during install it seems that it gets stuck when it attempts to load the 'get-pixels' dependency. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
import ColorThief from "colorthief";
import _ from 'lodash';

export const getPalette = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!url) {
            reject();
        }
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

        image.onload = function () {
            const colorThief = new ColorThief();
            const palette = colorThief.getPalette(this, 10);
            const result = _.uniq(palette, item => JSON.stringify(item));
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please describe your solution a little by editing your post. It could be helpful for OP

Answer (score 0):

This below code works for me. **version  :** "colorthief": "^2.3.2",

```
import ColorThief from "../../../node_modules/colorthief/dist/color-thief.mjs"; // your node modules path

export const getPalette = (url) => {
 return new Promise(resolve=>{
        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
        img.onload = () => {
            let colorThief = new ColorThief();
            resolve(colorThief.getPalette(img));
        }
        img.src = url;
    })
}
```