# can't reach the node contents of DIV with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, contenteditable

I use the setEndOfContenteditable function to put cursor at end of text when making a text-DIV editable.

```
//Insert cursor at end of contentEditable element
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
    }
}
```

When I used to have only one div, and the text right inside of that, this would work perfectly:

```
setEndOfContenteditable(curObj);
```

curObj being the DIV with the text in it.

Now I have switched to a design where I still have the curObj -div but only as a frame, and the DIV that contains the actual text is located inside of that. Normally I do this to reach (select) the inner div in my jQuery code

```
var curObj = window.curObj;
var inner = '#' + $(curObj).attr("id") + ' .object_inner';
$(inner).doAllMyStuff;
```

However that doesn't work with this particular setEndOfContenteditable function, the error I get is

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

and the error points at line 7 of the setEndOfContenteditable function:

```
range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I was trying to pass a jQuery selector to a plain javascript function (that expected a raw DOM element). Here is one solution, this gets the raw DOM element:

```
var spec = $(curObj).find('.object_inner');
setEndOfContenteditable(spec[0]);
```

Special thanks to this guy:
[How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)