# Meteor with blaze UI.Insert to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

i wanna to ask how to render and insert template to specific div.
As we know from meteor wiki, this how to do that :

```
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.something), document.body);
```

and i place that to rendered or onAfterAction on IronRouter map, and it works.
I have a div with id = "content", i wanna place the Template.something to that div, so i try with ordinary query code-like :

```
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.something), $('#content'));
```

and i place that to rendered or onAfterAction on IronRouter map, but it doesn't works.
please help me how to render and insert to specific div?
thanks

Comment: [How to get DOM node from a jQuery selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Comment: Sorry, i had tried it before, but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried using `yield`? It seems it is designed for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [documentation says](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_insert), UI.insert() expects a DOM node as its second argument.

```
UI.insert( UI.render( Template.something ), $( '#content' ).get(0) ));
```

If that is not working then try both `Template.something` and `$( '#content' ).get(0)` in then dev console to see what values they have.