# Inserting an HTML element after text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert some HTML after the user has selected some text on the page. I have it working but not optimally and there is one problem in particular:

It relies on the  element being on the page, but I don't want it to be. I want to do it all in the code, I am sure it's something relatively simple but need some help :)

I also welcome any other tips/suggestions/feedback!

The code canbe seen working here: http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/ (The selectionchange library is to make this work in FF).

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function (event) {
    var sel = this.getSelection();

    // If text is being selected by drag, to wait for them to finish selecting.
    jQuery("body").mouseup(function() {
      // Ensure there is some text selected and that it is more than one character.
      if (sel.toString().length > 1) {
        // We only want one #element on the page at a time.
        $("#element").remove();

        // @TODO: Remove dependency on this:
        var el = document.getElementById('selection');
        el.innerHTML = '<div id="element"></div>';
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;
        frag.appendChild(el.firstChild);

        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0)
        var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
        boundaryRange.collapse(false);
        boundaryRange.insertNode(frag);
        boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
        boundaryRange.collapse(true);
        // Clean up
        sel = '';
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Its not clear at all on what you are trying to achieve.  I can see what is happening by watching the html code on the fiddle.. but I'm still not clear on where you are going.  Question:  What is this line of code:  `var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;`  I don't understand the comma node thing...  is that just another empty variable, one that is never called?

Comment: I guess you get it now :) yes that node variable was unused and shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

Remove frag variable and directly add value in insertNode function like this :

```
boundaryRange.insertNode($('<div id="element"></div>')[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6zz8/

### Fix issue when to select right to left :

With a condition check if endOffset is smaller than startOffset.

```
var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
if (range.endOffset < range.startOffset) {
    startNode = range.endContainer;
    startOffset = range.endOffset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2c4qw/

## Solution 2

Remove unnecessary code, remove 'el' variable like this :

```
// @TODO: Remove dependency on this:
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;
$(frag).append($('<div id="element"></div>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zYSH4/

## Solution 3

Declare your variable like this `var el = $("<div></div>")[0];`. To get this :

```
// @TODO: Remove dependency on this:
var el = $("<div></div>")[0];
el.innerHTML = '<div id="element"></div>';
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;
frag.appendChild(el.firstChild);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L3Kf/

Comment: Hors, nicely done.  Solution 1 seems simple and complete.. but I'm not getting the why on Solution #2.  Why the $("<div></div>")[0] notation?  What is that, and why would you use that technique?  I can see its some sort of jQuery selector, its not clear on which one... why the [0]?

Comment: $("#element")[0] return javascript node (document.getElementById("element")). `$("body")[0] === document.body // true`

Comment: ooops.. you inserted a solution #2 on me. There were only two solutions before.. The new #2 makes sense.  I understand we want to cast an object that will work with .insertNode()  .. What I'm not getting is the new #3 with the $("<div></div>")[0] notation? What is that, and why would you use that technique? I can see its some sort of jQuery selector, its not clear on which one... why the [0]?  Is that just a code obfuscation technique.  (Its working! I'm obfuscated :^)

Comment: $("<div></div>")[0] is [$("<div></div>").get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/), [get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector).

Comment: Apologies for driving this into the ground.. but <div></div> doesn't really exist.  Is that a catch all for a DOM phantom element identifier?  How did you know that would even work?  (Note: I tried `<p></p>` and that totally worked because the fiddle had those elements.. but this example doesn't have any `<div>'s` in the body of the html (or are we relying that somewhere else in the jsfiddle management system there is a `<div>`?)  Oh, and many thanks for the links on the .get() to [0] translation.  Never seen that before...

Comment: It is like to use `document.createElement("p").textContent` the element doesn't exist but you can set text content.

Comment: Thank you! :) You've left an r off container inside that if statement - was getting an error.