# Using JS DOM, I want to get all input tags with the same name

Tags: javascript, dom

Hey guys I have this simple form and just need to know how to call for all the input tags with the name 'checks'.

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> A</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> B</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> C</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> D</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

so far the JS i have is:

```
function myFunc() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('input').name;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Comment: @ryan The OP isn't using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checks"]');
```

You could also use a `.forEach` loop to iterate over them:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checks"]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function (el) {
    console.log(el.name);
});
```

Of course you could also use [**`.getElementsByName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName):

```
document.getElementsByName('checks');
```

Comment: You would have to filter the results of `getElementsByName` if you want to make sure they are all inputs

Answer (score 1):

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```js
console.log( document.querySelectorAll('input[name=checks]') )
```

```html
<form>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> A</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> B</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> C</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checks"/> D</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**Document.getElementsByName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("checks");
```

And you'll get a NodeList object containing all these inputs.

Comment: Ugh, w3schools linkage =(

Comment: I changed the reference to Mozilla Developer Network. But what's wrong with w3school?

Comment: Also note that your example will fail if there are other elements that aren't input with the name set to checks

Comment: +1 for changing it to MDN: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @JuanMendes yes right, but the OP is using the same name for the inputs only.

Comment: @chsdk But I'm pretty sure there are other elements on the OP's page. You should always code defensively and make as few assumptions as possible.