# What is the difference between $("#id div") and $("#id > div")?

Tags: jquery

I'm confused with these two.

I have a table structure like following;

```
<div id="previewSection">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>X
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Y
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm `prepend` something in the table with Jquery. Now when I'm doing `$("#previewSection div")` it gives me something like `m.fn.init[253]` but when I call `$("#previewSection > div")` actually gives me the html like this `[<div>​…​</div>​]` which I originally wanted.

I've checked JQuery selectors and it said if I use `>` it gives direct child of the selector and if I don't use it all div of the selector; but both should give me the html `why I'm getting objects??` Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: The question is 'Where is my child?' against 'Where are all my descendants?

Comment: To answer your final question... jQuery always gives you an object. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector

Comment: But I'm not doing a get(0).. :(

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `X Y` and `X > Y` is that the latter will only select children (immediate descendants) of X.

Given this little snippet:

```
<div>
  <a>
    <span></span>
  </a>
</div>

div a       - works
div span    - works
div > a     - works
div > span  - nope, no span is an immediate descendant (child) of a div
```