# Use jQuery arguments in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I want to use a jQuery argument in a JavaScript function. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
window.nextGen = function(cell) {
    // code...
} 

window.prepareNextGen = function() {
    nextGen($('#grundtabelle').rows[1].cells[1]);
}
```

But that doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Fix**

To access the table object rows and cells you can simply add an array index like so:

```
nextGen( $('#grundtabelle')[0].rows[1].cells[1] );
```

See this previous question for more detail: [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
nextGen( $('#grundtabelle')[0].rows[1].cells[1] );



function nextGen( cell ) {
  
  console.info( cell.innerHTML );  // displays B1
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grundtabelle">
  <tr>
    <td>A0</td>
    <td>B0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object does not have a `rows` or `cells` property. Assuming you're trying to get the second `td` of the second `tr` (note that the indexes are zero-based, so the item with index of `1` is the second), then you need to use jQuery's DOM traversal methods. In this case, `find()` and `:eq`. Try this:

```
nextGen($('#grundtabelle').find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)'));
```

If the `nextGen()` function is expecting a DOMElement instead of a jQuery object then you can retrieve that from the jQuery object like this:

```
nextGen($('#grundtabelle').find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')[0]);
// or:
nextGen($('#grundtabelle').find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').get());
```