# jQuery UI Slider as Volume Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am in the process of developing a custom volume slider for FlowPlayer based on the standard jQuery UI Slider.
What I would like is some help connecting the slider with the HTML5 video volume controls.

This is the code that initiates the video

```
  <video id="mp3" autoplay>
  <source id="mp3source" src="mysource" type="audio/mp3">
```

I created a jQuery slider to control the volume

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
```

Is there a way I can manipulate the video volume depending on the slider's position ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you / give you impressions what to do:

```
$( "#slider" ).on( "slide", function( event, ui ) {
    $('#mp3')[0].volume = Math.round(ui.value / 100);
} );
```

- [JQueryUI slide Event description](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)
- [HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)
- [get the DOMElement from the jQuery Selector `$('#mp3')[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677910/4210443)