# how to retrieve an HTML attribute value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

Is it possible to retrieve the value of an HTML in jQuery
For example if i have the following html in the front-end 
`<h1 id="<%= course.ownByStudent[i].user._id%>">Hello World!</h1>`

I want to retrieve the value of the `id` which is `<%= course.ownByStudent[i].user._id%>` in the backend.

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. Let's say that the server response for `course.ownByStudent[i].user._id` is `server_id`.

So you can get the `h1` element using `document.querySelector('h1')`, then access to the `id` attribute as property of the `h1` element.

And the result is:

```js
var id = document.querySelector('h1').id;
alert(id);
```

```html
<h1 id="server_id">Hello World!</h1>
```

**jQuery version:**

```js
var id = $('h1')[0].id;
alert(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="server_id">Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: And with Jquery : $('h1').attr('id');

Comment: @Mosh Feu mind if i ask what the number zero refers to in this line var id = $('h1')[0].id;

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Sure. `$('h1')` returns **jQuery collection**. The `[0]` "pointing" to the first **DOM** element in this collection.You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1677910/863110) answer.

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks a lot for the elaboration. Am testing it now :)

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi My pleasure :) Let me know if you are OK.