# How to add attribute to all titles on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I would like to find all elements which contains `title` on page and add new attribute to all of them.

Example:

```
<div title='something 1'></div>
<p>Test<div title='something 2'></div></p>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div title='something 3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How it should look like after page load:

```
<div title='something 1' rel='tooltip'></div>
<p>Test<div title='something 2' rel='tooltip'></div></p>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div title='something 3' rel='tooltip'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Previously I did it manually which is bad solution for me

```
$('#collection_map > div > div > button').attr('rel', 'tooltip');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
$('div[title]').each(function() {
$(this).attr('rel', 'tooltip');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all elements which have attribute `title` and then loop over it to add new attribute `rel` to each object.

`paragraph` tag cannot have block elements like `div` nested in it. See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically
>   close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>`
>   tag.

```js
 $('[title]').attr('rel', 'tooltip');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title='something 1'></div>
<p>Test
  <div title='something 2'></div>
</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div title='something 3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `$('[title]').attr('rel', 'tooltip')` ... loop will occur internally

Comment: @charlietfl - aah yes. Mixed javascript :) Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need jQuery for this. Here is a working example in plain JavaScript.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[title]')

elems.forEach(elem => elem.setAttribute('rel', 'tooltip'))
```

```html
<div title='something 1'></div>
<p>Test<div title='something 2'></div></p>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div title='something 3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```