# How to get DOM element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get result that is clicked DOM element.

When I try below code, it return jQuery object.

my desired result is like this

`<td>1</td>` ← clicked DOM element

Are there any method to get this?

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
console.log($(this));
})
});
```

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't wrap `this` in JQuery.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
console.log(this);
})
});
```

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `$(this)` to `this`

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
console.log(this);
})
});
```

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').on('click', function() { /* your click event */
    console.log("you clicked", this);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `console.log($(this))` to `console.log(this)` in your click event.

Because JQuery using only `this` not wrapped `$(this)`.