# How to use jquery content with Vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, constructor

I am trying to make it so that this code I wrote doesn't rely on having to access the dom in order to use its contents. I had already accessed the dom once before using jquery, and I want to be able to use the jquery I wrote instead of writing new code to access it. Here is my code so far:

```
  constructor($navigation, $content) {

    if ($navigation.length == 0 || $content.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    var nav1 = document.getElementById("main-nav");
    var btns = nav1.getElementsByClassName("nav");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }
    $navigation.on('click', 'li', function () {
      $content.hide();
      $($content[$(this).index()]).show();
    });
  }
```

And here is where I had accessed the dom in another document:

```
   new Faq($("#main-nav"), $("div[class='faq-container']"));
```

what I want to do is make is so that var nav1 and var btns can make use of $navigation and $content, instead of accessing the dom directly. Do I have to somehow convert this code to jquery? how would I approach that?

Comment: $navigation.find('#main-nav')

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why do you want to switch part of your code to vanilla DOM manipulation? It'd make much more sense to choose *one* style, then stick with it everywhere

Comment: I don't think you quite understand DOM access. jQuery ***is*** directly accessing the DOM just as vanilla JS would. jQuery is just JavaScript that someone else wrote - - it's not magic.

Comment: I understand that jquery access the dom; what I want is to re use what I wrote in jquery instead of having to access the dom again in the other variables I had listed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would love to convert it to jquery; I am rather inexperienced with Jquery so I am unsure as to how to re-write it so the whole thing is jquery

Comment: To convert `$("#main-nav")` to `doc.getEById("main-nav")` (I can't even bring myself to write that out it's so tedious.. but that's off topic) - you add `[0]` in your case `var nav1 = $navigation[0]` or use [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes!!! thank you! that works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the question as:

> I have already accessed the DOM once using jquery, and I want to be able to use this variable with vanilla javascript rather than access the DOM a second time

To get the DOM node from a jquery object, you add `[0]` or `.get(0)`

```js
function example(jqueryObj)
{
    jqueryObj[0].innerText = "set via [0]";
}

example($("#div"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Specific to the question, to convert between `$("#main-nav")` and the  `doc.getElementById("main-nav")` equivalent, you would use

```
var nav1 = $navigation[0]
```

---

As a bonus, here's your function jquery-ified

```js
constructor(navigation, content) {

  if (navigation.length == 0 || content.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  navigation.on("click", ".nav", function() {
      $("nav.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  navigation.on('click', 'li', function() {
    content.hide();
    $(content[$(this).index()]).show();
  });
}

new Faq($("#main-nav"), $("div.faq-container"));
```